# arcpy.JSONToFeatures_conversion and json module conflict

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.3, json, error-001558

I'm using [arcpy.JSONToFeatures_conversion()](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/conversion-toolbox/json-to-features.htm) to batch convert some json files to features in a gdb. Python kept running into errors (either ERROR 001558: Error parsing json file, or ERROR 999998). This was troubling since I had previously tested the input/output without issue. After a lot of troubleshooting I found the error only occurs after the json module was imported. What is the most pythonic way of dealing with this? Can anyone explain the conflict and how I might recognize/anticipate this when troubleshooting code in the future?

Full error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#10>", line 1, in <module>
    arcpy.JSONToFeatures_conversion(in_json_file, out_features)
  File "C:\ArcGIS\Desktop10.3\ArcPy\arcpy\conversion.py", line 528, in JSONToFeatures
    raise e
ExecuteError: ERROR 001558: Error parsing json file 'L:/<dir>results16870.json'. 
Failed to execute (JSONToFeatures).
```

Code Snippet (works when json isn't imported):

```
import arcpy
import json
temp_json = r"~\result1216.json"
fcName = r"~\Testing.gdb\newFC"
arcpy.JSONToFeatures_conversion(temp_json, fcName)
```

Screen shot of code/process and error (note the same input/output):
[image]

Comment: Just shot in the dark. The import json could be in conflict with another module with the same name. Try using “import json as jsonlib” or something to that effect so it doesn’t use the json namespace

Comment: Please always provide code snippets as formatted text rather than pictures.

Comment: can you copy/paste the json into jsonlint.com and confirm its valid?